# How to assign a specific number to QListWidget so that it can be modified later?

Tags: c++, qt, qtgui

Are there any way to assign a specific `int` number to a `QListWidget` item?

I am creating a lot of instances of my designed `widget` class by doing the following each time and setting some data by passing them as arguments

```
MyWidgetClass *object = new MyWidgetClass(this);
object->setData(data_1,data_2,.....,data_n);
```

then I am setting this widget to ui's `qListWidget` with the help of `QListWidgetItem` by this:

```
QListWidgetItem *listWidgetItem = new QListWidgetItem(ui->qListWidget);
ui->qListWidget->addItem(listWidgetItem);
listWidgetItem->setSizeHint(object->sizeHint());
ui->qListWidget->setItemWidget (listWidgetItem, object);
```

Later depending on the signal received, the already passed data will have to be modified automatically. So, I thought, if any specific number is assigned to each item of `QListWidget`, then it can be modified at any time automatically.

Any helps or suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: If I well understand your question, you have to use QSignalMapper. Qt documentation say : "The QSignalMapper class bundles signals from identifiable senders.
This class collects a set of parameterless signals, and re-emits them with integer, string or widget parameters corresponding to the object that sent the signal."

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following to store a custom data in a list widget item:

```
int identifier = 111;
QListWidgetItem *listWidgetItem = new QListWidgetItem(ui->qListWidget);
listWidgetItem->setData(Qt::UserRole, identifier);
```

and this to retrieve it back:

```
int identifier = listWidgetItem->data(Qt::UserRole).toInt();
```

Comment: How to relate this 'int' number with QListWidget instances?

Comment: You can invent your indexation.

Comment: QListWidgetItem objects have been declared inside a function. Once the function execution is completed, no objects of QListWidgetItem can be used in code again. So assign a number to QListWidget dynamic object is more helpful. But how to assign or how to use it later to trace it?

Comment: Well, but you can get the same items latter in another function using `QListWidget::item()` or `QListWidget::itemAt()` or `QListWidget::currentItem()` functions. Once getting pointer to the item you can get the identifier you assigned to it.